# how to run the same matlab function continuously in parallel

Tags: matlab, timer, parallel-processing, matlab-guide

I am new to Matlab and I am currently working on a matlab code that captures an image and detects the amount of waste on that image. I already have the code where an image is captured and the amount of waste is detected on this image.
 However, this code is for one camera only. I wonder how can I make this code work for more than one camera so that multiple cameras can work simultaneously in parallel.

let's say I have 3 cameras installed instead of one. What could be the way to make the three cameras to use the same code to run in parallel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use timer in MATLAB to run a function at a fixed interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120178/how-to-use-timer-in-matlab-to-run-a-function-at-a-fixed-interval)

Comment: Dear Argyll, Thak you very much for your reply. I was able to put my code inside a timer function and make it work repeatedly. However, the timer function run over and over for one camera only. I would appreciate sharing a way where I can run this timer function for multiple cameras in parallel.

Comment: Have you tried using 3 different timers? It'd be 3 lines of the timer function one after another. The idea of using event listener + handler objects is exactly so that things run in parallel. Let me know if the `timer` function already does.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Although the different timers did not work in parallel, your answer inspired me to run different timers in serial. However, I appreciate if you can share a way where I can generate a new timer based on user configuration. For example, whenever the user clicks a button a new timer will be created and start running.

Comment: If you need trigger condition for the start of the timer, all you need is to place the `start` method at the right place. If you need an event driven response more complex than waiting a few seconds, you need to create your own [Event and Listener](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html) classes.

Comment: Dear Argyll, Thank you very much for your continuous support. I have read event and listeners topic but I think it is not what I am looking for. I am trying to find a way where the number of timers can be determined by the user. For example, if the user wants the app to have 3 cameras, there will be 3 timer variables. and if the user decided to add a new camera later, there will be forth timer added and so on.

Comment: I see. If your test result is that different instances of `timer` cannot run in parallel, I don't think you can use `timer` directly to create that. *However*, in my test, I found that different `timer` instances can queue tasks in parallel. I'll need to write this in an answer. So please see below.

Answer (score 0):

Different instances of `timer` do queue tasks in parallel by default.

For example, with

```
t1=timer;
t2=timer;
t3=timer; % Calling the constructor in separate occasions should create independent instances.

t1.StartDelay=2;
t2.StartDelay=3;
t3.StartDelay=5; % please print the fields to screen to see that t1, t2, t3 are not linked

[t1.TimerFcn, t2.TimerFcn, t3.TimerFcn]=deal(@(~,~)disp(num2str(toc)));

start(t1);start(t2);start(t3);tic
```

My result is

```
1.9977
3.005
5.0011
```

(As you can see, `timer` is not very precise. You should see different but similar results.)

From the result, you can see that `timer` *by default*, ie. a single call of `TimerFcn` per `timer` instance, queue tasks in parallel. Had it not been the case, you should see 2, 5, 10 in the cmd.

Thus you can adapt `TimerFcn` in the above example to your context. If you have particular problems in your context, please specify in your question the issues you run into in a [concrete, minimal, self-contained and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

For periodic calls, you may have to adjust the `'BusyMode'` field or use your custom [handler class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html).